# ACM-ICPC 7384 programming challenge

Tags: java

I'm trying to solve the Popular Vote problem, but I get runtime error and have no idea why, I really appreciate the help. Basically my solution is to get the total of votes, if all candidates have the same amount of votes; then there's no winner, otherwise I calculate the percentage of votes the winner gets in order to know if he's majority or minority winner.

```
import java.util.Scanner;


class popular {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
     int n, suma, mayoria;
     int casos=s.nextInt();
     int cont=0;
     int ganador=0;
     float num=0;
     while(cont!=casos){
         n=s.nextInt();
         int votos[]= new int[n];
         for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            votos[i] = s.nextInt();
        }
         suma=sumar(votos);
         if(suma==-1){
             System.out.println("no winner");
         }
         else{
             ganador=ganador(votos, suma);
             num=(float)votos[ganador]/(float)suma;
             if( num> 0.5){
                 System.out.println("majority winner "+(ganador+1));
             }
             else{
                 System.out.println("minority winner "+(ganador+1));
            }  
         }
         cont++;
         ganador=0;

     }
 }

 public static int sumar(int arreglo[]){
     int resp1=-1, resp=0;
     int temp=arreglo[0];
     boolean sol=true;
     for (int i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i++) {
         resp=resp+arreglo[i];
         if(temp!=arreglo[i]){
             sol=false;
         }
     }
     if(sol==false){
         return resp;
     }
     return resp1;
 }

 public static int ganador(int arreglo[], int suma){
     int mayor=0;
     int ganador=0;
     for (int i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i++) {
         if(arreglo[i]>mayor){
             mayor=arreglo[i];
             ganador=i;
         }
     }
     return ganador;
 }
```

}

Comment: What specifically is the error? Is it not compiling or is it a logic error

Comment: it's runtime error, according to official documentation it means: "Your program failed during the execution (segmentation fault, floating point exception...). The exact cause is not reported to the user to avoid hacking.".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I submitted your code to the OJ, but I didn't get a runtime error, but I got Compilation error. I have to figure out there are some problems in your code. First of all, if you want to submit a java code to OJ, you need to name the public class as Main instead of popular or something else. Second, your code logic is not correct. Suppose a test case:

```
4 
1
1
2
2
```

Your program will print "minority winner 3" but it's should be "no winner".

Here is a modified source code from yours (you can get accepted with this code):

```
import java.util.Scanner;


class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n, suma, mayoria;
        int casos = s.nextInt();
        int cont = 0;
        int ganador = 0;
        float num = 0;
        while (cont != casos) {
            n = s.nextInt();
            int votos[] = new int[n];
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                votos[i] = s.nextInt();
            }

            ganador = findMaximum(votos);

            if (getMaximumCount(votos, votos[ganador]) > 1) {
                System.out.println("no winner");
            } else {
                suma = sumOf(votos);
                if (votos[ganador] * 2 > suma) {
                    System.out.println("majority winner " + (ganador + 1));
                } else {
                    System.out.println("minority winner " + (ganador + 1));
                }
            }
            cont++;
            ganador = 0;
        }
    }

    private static int sumOf(int[] arreglo) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int x : arreglo) {
            sum += x;
        }
        return sum;
    }

    private static int getMaximumCount(int[] arreglo, int maximum) {
        // Check if there are more than one items have the maximum value
        int count = 0;
        for (int x : arreglo) {
            if (x == maximum) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

    private static int findMaximum(int[] arreglo) {
        int x = 0, pos = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i++) {
            if (x < arreglo[i]) {
                x = arreglo[i];
                pos = i;
            }
        }
        return pos;
    }
}
```

Hope it could help you!

Comment: Yes it helped me a lot, now I see my mistake, thank you very much for your help.